# notification bug

Tags: 20.04

so I noticed that if the character ' is included in a pop-up notification, instead of showing it it shows a weird string starting with # and ending with ;
Also that string is not always the same.
I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and I would appreciate any help on this.

I tried notify-send "  '  " on the terminal and the notification message was fine, so the issue could be app-specific, I mostly get this error from discord.

Comment: Can you please [edit] the question and provide examples?

Comment: ChanganAuto it's a bit difficult because there has to be a notification including ', but I'll try.